# google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinService has leaked ServiceConnection error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a project which has google map right at the first activity.When i switch off the phone and restart it , The map is not shown according to my requirements.It is shown at world level.I got the following error in the logcat:

```
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066): Service com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinService has leaked ServiceConnection gbd@4064bc48 that was originally bound here
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.checkin.CheckinService has leaked ServiceConnection gbd@4064bc48 that was originally bound here
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:995)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at gbc.<init>(SourceFile:99)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at gay.<init>(SourceFile:226)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at xs.<init>(SourceFile:175)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at bkt.a(SourceFile:226)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at bks.a(SourceFile:298)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at bks.doInBackground(SourceFile:288)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-31 14:53:04.909: E/ActivityThread(2066):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

How do i solve the above error.The issue goes away when i restart the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992859/licensechecker-checkaccess-leaks-serviceconnection

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a asynchronous method that has already been called but has not completed. Look at your code (see if you call it once on start/create, and once later) and possible add a flag to stop this from happening.